# Error in updating records using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am having a problem with an MySQL Update query. Here is the code:

```
String s2="foo";
String s6="bar";

try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection       con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb","root","root");
String query="update mydb set Status='"+s6+"' where IC_Number='"+s2+"'";
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
con.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println("Error in login:"+e);
}
}
}
```

I get the error

> can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().

Can anyone point out where the problem is ?

Comment: What is error you are getting?

Comment: my record was not updated... But now problem solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `update` operation you have to use `executeUpdate` which returns an integer but not a `ResultSet`

**Change**:

```
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

**To**:

```
int updateResult = stmt.executeUpdate( query );
```

**Documentation**:

- [java.sql.Statement.executeUpdate(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String))

  - Executes the given SQL statement, which may be an INSERT, UPDATE, or
    DELETE statement or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as an
    SQL DDL statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should use executeUpdate() instead of executeQuery();